# How can I change my "check" to not error?

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
@client.command(name="reactionrole", description="none")
async def reactionrole_cmd(ctx):
  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author
  choose_reaction = discord.Embed(
    title = "Step one | Choose reaction",
    description = "**React** to this message with the reaction trigger",
    color = 0x78AFD0
  )
  await ctx.send(embed=choose_reaction)
  msg1 = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check) 

  find_message = discord.Embed(
    title = "Step two | Find Message",
    description = "**Mention** the channel this message is in.",
    color = 0x78AFD0
  )
  await ctx.send(embed=find_message)
  msg2 = await client.wait_for('channel_mentions', check=check)

  await ctx.send("hi")
```

I'm attempting to make a "reaction role command", but the error is

Command raised an exception: TypeError: check() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How can I fix this?

Comment: For a `reaction_add` check, you will need two arguments. `reaction` and `user` in order

Comment: @12944qwerty I don't really know what you mean

Comment: You know how events work right? `on_message`, `on_reaction_add`, etc? `wait_for()` works the same way. The first argument is the event's name (without the `on_`) and the arguments are the exact same

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your reaction_add check as 12944qwerty mentioned. The reaction_add `msg1 = await client.wait_for('reaction_add, check=check)` uses your check function

```
def check(m):
    return user == ctx.author
```

but reaction_add takes two arguments `reaction` & `user` so you need to change your check to take both reaction & user, do something like this.

```
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author
```